# How do I separate files in groups for aggregate processing?

Tags: bash

Suppose I have lots of files in a directory, and I need to concatenate clusters up to 100 files into a new file.

How could I do this in bash?

*For the purpose of this question, let's assume that I don't need to sort them in any fashion before clustering*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find` + `xargs`:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n100 process.sh
```

`xargs` groups the files by hundreds, `find` helps it understand files with whitespace in their names.

*Update*:

In `process.sh`, just find the first non-existent name and create the file:

```
i=0
while [[ -f concatenated-$i ]] ; do (( i++ )) ; done
cat "$@" > concatenated-$i
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! If I may ask, how would you concatenate the output of `xargs` in a separate set of files?

Comment: @tilacog: See the update.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still couldn't understand how to do this. I tried to run the process.sh like you said, but it said `xargs: process.sh: No such file or directory`. Would you mind giving me an usage example, please? Thanks!

Comment: @tilacog: I created `process.sh` with exactly the contents shown here, just prepend a shebang (`#!/bin/bash`). If it is not placed in the directory when you run `find`, specify full path to it for `xargs`.